# Elasticsearch search Java API doesn't give correct results

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have following code for ES search:

```
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    qb = QueryBuilders.termQuery("title", "Java");
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
    searchSourceBuilder.from(0);
    searchSourceBuilder.size(5);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("myindex");
    searchRequest.types("books");
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse sr = client.search(searchRequest);
    System.out.println(sr.getHits().totalHits);
```

It gives me no results, even though there are documents meeting this criteria.
When I run similar term query from Kibana, I get results:

```
GET /myindex/books/_search
{
   "query":
   {
     "term" : {
       "title" : {
       "value" : "java"
       }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is `Java` (with uppercase) in your Java code and `java` (in lowercase) in your Kibana query.

Since you're doing a `term` query, the case matters. If you used a `match` query, the case doesn't matter and both would work as you expect.